# Perceptron not training correctly - error in loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, enumerate, perceptron

I'm trying to implement a simple perceptron in python that will be able to classify logical functions like OR, or AND.

[image: Example AND-gate]

I have the following code in python:

The bias is the third entry in each input vector. There is a row vector, 'targets', which contains the 'correct' values, the labels:

The problem is that the weights do not update properly. They remain random, which tells me that nothing is really being trained.

```
inputs = np.array([
[0,0,1],
[0,1,1],
[1,0,1],
[1,1,1],
])
targets = np.array([0,0,0,1])

def step_function(x):
    return 1 * (x>=0)

def train(x,y):
    rate = 0.1
    trials = 10
    errors = []
    w = np.random.rand(len(inputs[0]))

    for t in range(trials):
        for i, x in enumerate(inputs):

            actual = np.dot(inputs[i], w)
            desired = targets[i]
            error = desired - step_function(actual)

            if error != 0:
                errors.append(error)
                w += rate * error * inputs[i]

    return w

w = train(inputs, targets)
print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `step_function` is not correct. You can skip that function and just change:

```
#this
error = desired - step_function(actual)
#to
error = desired - actual
```

The result is not going to be a perfect 1 and 0, but will do the work that I think you're aiming at. In the future you can use a sigmoid function or something else to try to have a result closer to 0 and 1.